# Module Not found - pipenv

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, pipenv

I am trying to use pipenv in a project. The project is the following:

https://github.com/thiery-lab/manifold_lifting

I did the following:

```
mkdir project
cd project 
git clone https://github.com/thiery-lab/manifold_lifting.git
cd manifold_lifting 
pipenv install
pipenv shell
```

So theoricaly pipenv installed all the python modules present in the requirements.txt. If i do a >cat Pipfile , all the packages are there.
But if i do the following:

```
python3
import numpy
```

i get the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Why is this happening? Isn't suppose to work? I tried pipenv python3 and then import numpy, didn't work either. Tried with python2 too, but i got the same result. And this happens for every module/package that the Pipfile lists.

And if i try to run the jupyter notebook, which is my objective, it doesn't work either.

I don't know what do anymore, so i appreciate any help.

Comment: After you run `pipenv shell` what does `which python` return?

Comment: it returned: /home/caio/.local/share/virtualenvs/manifold_lifting-9Tsx2wsk/bin/python

Comment: So that suggests the pipenv shell is properly activated. I don't use pipenv often so I don't know if it installs a `python3` symlink. Try just running `python`

Comment: @Iguananaut Sadly i get the same error with just python.

Answer (score 2):

I just created the shell with:

```
pipenv --three install
```

And it worked!